# How to apply color function (e.g. Hue) to Image3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, plot-themes, image3d

I have a 3d image data `PlotData1`, and I want to plot the `Image3D` with color. I tried this (Note: I don't have `Plot1` in my actual case. I only have `PlotData1`):-

```
Plot1 = Import["ExampleData/CTengine.tiff", "Image3D"];
PlotData1 = ImageData@Plot1;
PlotData1Filtered = PlotData1 /. x_ /; x < 0.2 -> 0;
PlotData1Normlalized = PlotData1Filtered/Max[Flatten@PlotData1Filtered]; 
Image3D[PlotData1Normlalized, ColorFunction -> "Hue"]
```

But I just have the grayscale 3D without color. But I need color based on the different intensity of the pixels (i.e. voxels).

[image]

I also tried `Image3D[PlotData1Normlalized, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, intensity}, Hue[intensity]]]`, but it doesn't work. What can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intensity is the first argument given to the color function, so you got the arguments wrong. We also need to make the background transparent. Here is an example:

```
Image3D[PlotData1Normlalized, ColorFunction -> (If[
     # == 0,
     Transparent,
     Hue[#, 1, 1, 0.1]
     ] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The `0.1` is the opacity. If you don't want to use opacity, you can simply use `Hue[#]`.